# Scoped style gets overriden by Vuetify

Tags: sass, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt 3 and Vuetify to create a website. I want to give some margin to an anchor tag inside my Vue component. For this I'm used to using some scoped styling.

For example:
`<style lang="scss" scoped> a{margin:16px} </style>`

However if I inspect the element the margin is 0.
I can see that the margin gets overriden by inline styling by Vuetify, namely:

```
inline:95
* {
  padding: 0; /* Reset `padding` and `margin` of all elements */
  margin: 0;
}
```

I tried the following:

This is my template code:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <v-text-field
        variant="outlined"
        v-model="password"
        type="password"
        label="Password"
        :rules="[required]"
        class="mb-0"
      />
      <a href="mailto:X">{{ $t('login.forgot') }}</a>
      <v-btn
        :loading="userStore.loading"
        :disabled="!formInvalid"
        type="submit"
        variant="flat"
        color="primary"
        block
        :error="error"
        class="mb-6"
        >Log in</v-btn
      >
      <a href="mailto:X">{{
        $t('login.new_account')
      }}</a>
      <v-alert
        v-if="error"
        closable
        class="mt-2"
        title="Invalid credentials"
        text="Please check your e-mail and password"
        type="error"
        variant="tonal"
      ></v-alert>
    </v-form>
  </div>
</template>
```

For this page I use a nuxt layout like this:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="content">
        <slot />
      </div>
      <brand-message id="branding" />
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

These are the relevant parts of my nuxt config file:

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'
const description = 'Close Builder'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,

  typescript: {
    typeCheck: false,
    strict: true
  },
  css: ['@/assets/styles/main.scss'],
  vite: { css: { preprocessorOptions: { scss: { additionalData: '@use "@/assets/styles/global.scss" as *;' } } } },
  sourcemap: {
    server: false,
    client: false
  },
  modules: [
    '@sidebase/nuxt-auth',
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    'nuxt-icons',
    '@pinia/nuxt',
    // eslint-disable-next-line require-await
    async (_options, nuxt) => {
      nuxt.hooks.hook('vite:extendConfig', (config) =>
        // @ts-ignore
        config.plugins.push(vuetify())
      )
    }
  ],
}
```

This is my main.scss

```
@use 'vuetify' with (
  $utilities: false,
  $color-pack: false
);
```

My global.scss only imports all kinds of mixins and variables.

How can I use scoped styling in combination with Vuetify?
My guess is that my scoped styling is imported before Vuetify and therefore overwritten later? But how do I change that?